# How can i prevent temporary bans for my bot from discord.com, when i am using Replit?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I am a bit new to Discord.py……
How can I prevent Temporary Bot Bans from Discord.py on Replit ?
I also need to edit my code fairly well… so I can’t spend 15 minutes to run it everytime.

Is there any other Suggestion ?
Please help…
Thanks for your help  :)

Answer (score 1):

Discord blocks Replit a lot due to the fact that many bots are hosted there and they go over the rate limits pretty quickly, so I would suggest getting an actual hosting company. Companies like Pebblehost, Vultr, and Linode do a pretty good job. You can also switch over to Glitch, it is pretty good but VERY VERY VERY slow compared to Replit.

Comment: ok, thanks a lot ! I'll try using Glitch...